# Checkbox uncheck when submit form

Tags: jquery, html

I am not sure is this a bugs in jQuery when using `.click()` function instead of `.change()` function for checkbox. It's working well on [jsfiddle](http://webcollect.viewscast.com/canonrepairmobile) 
[1](http://webcollect.viewscast.com/canonrepairmobile): http://jsfiddle.net/fadlisaad/tSgbZ/16/ but not on the live page http://webcollect.viewscast.com/canonrepairmobile

You may test it with this sequence:

1. Language > English
2. Country > United Kingdom
3. Click 'Continue'
4. Choose any option and click 'Continue' for the next 3 question until you found question 'Prior to having your product repaired which steps did you take to try and resolve the problem?'
5. try to choose the last option 'None of the above' and click continue. During the loading to the next question, the checked option is mysteriously unchecked itself, so if you view the source on the next page, you will find `<INPUT TYPE="Hidden" ID="__OUTP__ResolveWay_7" NAME="__OUTP__ResolveWay_7" VALUE="">` which should be `<INPUT TYPE="Hidden" ID="__OUTP__ResolveWay_7" NAME="__OUTP__ResolveWay_7" VALUE="1">`

   It's just working fine with the others checkboxes. Could someone figure it out why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this code:

```
$('input[name!="ResolveWay_7"]').click(function() {
    $('input[name="ResolveWay_7"]').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

you make it so that each time there's a click on an input, the checkbox is deactivated. So when you click on the submit button (yes, that's also an input) it unchecks the checkbox.

I believe you only need to change the selector to `$('input[type="checkbox"][name!="ResolveWay_7"]')` and it should work.

Comment: So, there is any different on using `click()` or `change()` function? It seem identical to me on this case.

Comment: There are differences between click and change (for example you can click on an already selected element and it will not change), but that wouldn't affect the behavior you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this piece of code:

```
$('input[name!="ResolveWay_7"]').click(function() {
    $('input[name="ResolveWay_7"]').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

Your **Continue** button is also going to satisfy that jQuery selector as it is of type `<input>` and is not called ResolveWay_7.  Therefore when the Continue button is clicked, it will deselect the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the bottom of the source code of the page where you select "None of the above".

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
/* <![CDATA[ */
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#comment').hide();
    $('#specify').click(function() {
        $('#comment').toggle();
        $('textarea').val('');
    });
    $('input[name="ResolveWay_7"]').change(function() {
        $('input[name!="ResolveWay_7"]').removeAttr('checked');
        $('textarea').val('');
        $('#comment').hide();
    });
    $('input[name!="ResolveWay_7"]').click(function() {
        $('input[name="ResolveWay_7"]').removeAttr('checked');
    });
});
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

There are 2 places there where it says:

```
$('input[name="ResolveWay_7"]').removeAttr('checked');
```

Comment: Yes, that is used so that if we check the 'None of this', all the other checkbox will be uncheck, @Chris were right

Comment: @FadliSaad: Yup. I was refuting James's claim that there are two places that remove the checked attribute from that input. As you say, one removes it from that input and one removes it from all the others.

Answer (score 1):

check this:

```
$('input[name!="ResolveWay_7"]').click(function() {
    $('input[name="ResolveWay_7"]').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

when you click on any input except `ResolveWay_7` it clears `checked` property of it (`Resolveway_7`) and submit button (continue) is also an input so clicking it clears checkbox.
You need to exclude button from selection like:

```
$('input[name!="ResolveWay_7"]').not("input.myButton").click(.......);
```

Comment: If I use other than `<input type="button">` it should be ok right? Such as `<button>..</button>`